# How to remap a topic in rviz that is issued by plugin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I remap a topic in rqt that is issued by rviz plugin. I am trying to remap topic initialpose to myinitialpose. But when I use the set pose from the rviz menu it still publishes on the old topic.

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2013-10-22 10:12:12,008: process[rqt_gui-6]: args[[u'/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui', u'initialpose:=myinitialpose', u'__name:=rqt_gui']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2013-10-22 10:12:12,009: process[rqt_gui-6]: start w/ args [[u'/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui', u'initialpose:=myinitialpose', u'__name:=rqt_gui', u'__log:=/home/viki/.ros/log/9c1746f4-3b23-11e3-b242-28cfe95d78b1/rqt_gui-6.log']]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93121/how-to-remap-a-topic-in-rviz-that-is-issued-by-plugin/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I still question how to do this, my immediate concern on remapping initialpose can be done via the rivz properties panel.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0